# Python CICD pipeline

Tags: python, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

In my company , we do CICD on java/groovy/node etc projects by following steps:

1)- Package an application using a build tool (maven,node,gradle etc). Push the snapshot/release version in a binary repo (artifactory/nexus etc).

2)- Increment the version if its a release or create a snapshot (using the same build tool like maven)

3)- Scan the package using sonar and clm

4)- If passed , create a docker image and deploy.

Now I want to create a similar CICD pipeline for Python based application.
I am confused on Point#1 #2 and #3 . How do I package a Python code ? How do I scan the jars those are installed through pip ? Because once I run pip the jars are not just downloaded , instead they are installed. Also , how do I version the code , Is there a build tool that I can use for this purpose with Python.

Comment: You end up figuring out how to do this? I'm also attempting to do this.

Comment: @ChrisRisley I Answered the post now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing :

[image: testme]